# What about change cassandra LeveledCompactionStrategy fanout option to 100 or even bigger?

Tags: cassandra

I have one table having 2T data saved in c* each machine.
And if using `LCS`, the data will have 5 level:

- L1: 160M * 10 = 1.6G
- L2: 1.6G * 10 = 16G
- L3: 16G * 10 = 160G
- L4: 160G * 10 = 1.6T
- L5: 1.6T * 10 = 16T

When I look into the source code, I found an option: `fanout_size`.

The default value is 10.
What about change this value to 100?
Then the level will reduce to 3:

- L1: 160M * 100 = 16G
- L2: 16G * 100 = 1.6T
- L3: 1.6T * 100 = 160T

Or even could I set this to 10000?
Could this can help resolve the write amplify problem?

Currently I am using STCS. I want to solve 2 problem, I don't know wheather LCS with this option can help me resolve them:

- compaction is too slow especially with large file(100G per file)
- read concurrent is pool (10 concurrent then the disk io is full)(no ssd here)

Answer (score 0):

Generally the solution people use is to increase the `sstable_size_in_mb`. For what its worth though you would want to decrease this, not increase (ie set to 6) which might help write amplification *a little*.

What is the issue your trying to solve? Have you considered other compaction strategies if this is a problem?

Comment: Currently I am using stcs. And the concurrent seems not good enough. Disk IO is super high(160M) when 10 concurrent. STCS finally compact to seval files, the performance better. but I still want to find a better way to support more concurrent read. And Write is a little versus read, maybe 1:100.

Comment: You would probably want LCS then. 5 levels isnt that bad, is it causing an actual problem? That means max-ish of 5 sstables per read which with STCS with 2T would be like 20-30 most likley